# snowflake jdbc paramter returning VARCHAR for all datatypes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake JDBC driver is reporting parameter metadata for all the datatypes as VARCHAR. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

DDL:-
CREATE TABLE INTTABLE(INTCOL INTEGER)

Below is the output from Snowflake ODBC Driver

```
SQLPrepare:
In:StatementHandle = 0x00000000021B1B50, StatementText = "INSERT INTO INTTABLE(INTCOL) VALUES(?)", TextLength = 42
Return: SQL_SUCCESS=0

SQLDescribeParam:
In:StatementHandle = 0x00000000021B1B50, ParameterNumber = 1, DataTypePtr = 0x00000000001294D0, ParameterSizePtr = 0x0000000000126950,DecimalDigits =0x0000000000126980, NullablePtr = 0x00000000001269B0
Return: SQL_SUCCESS=0
Out:*DataTypePtr = SQL_VARCHAR=12, *ParameterSizePtr = 16777216, *DecimalDigits = 0, *NullablePtr = SQL_NULLABLE=1
```

Below is Output with Snowflake JDBC Driver.

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO INTTABLE(INTCOL) VALUES(?)");

ParameterMetaData psmd = ps.getParameterMetaData();

for(int i=1 ;i<=psmd.getParameterCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(psmd.getParameterType(i)+ "  " + psmd.getParameterTypeName(i));
}
```

Output:-
12  text

Comment: Mithun, you need to provide much more information around this question. What have you tried and can you show examples? I use the JDBC driver for Snowflake and the datatypes show correctly. Pleas refer to the following as a guideline for asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Most likely your problems are in your code, eg. not actually checking _different_ parameters.

Comment: @Mithun can you please edit your question with the following: A table description and sample code - and then what you want it to look like, including the types. In this situation it is usually easier to prepare the data with the types before loading, but this will depend on what you are expecting instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for adding more information to your thread. I still may be doing a little guesswork though.

If you are trying to change the table values type from Varchar, and there are no values in it, you can drop the table, then re-recreate it.

If you want to ALTER what is already in the table try altering the table first: [Manual Reference](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html)

There is also the CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE(col , col 2 ) that takes care of both.

Is this what you are looking for?